# How to replace a string in Powershell where there are multiple occurrences of it

Tags: xml, powershell, replace

Currently I use the following to replace string `Mock` with `Sun` in Powershell script for the below Web.config file.

`((Get-Content -path "Web.config" -Raw) -replace 'Mock','Sun'))`

```
    <add key="SourceRepository" value="Sun" />
    <add key="Product" value="Sun" />
  </appSettings>
```

How do I make sure to replace only this entry `<add key="Product" value="Sun" />` and not `<add key="SourceRepository" value="Sun" />`

I've tried using RegEx, could not find a solution, any suggestions on how to go about this one

Comment: why cant you just `((Get-Content -path "Web.config" -Raw) -replace '<add key="Product" value="Mock" />','<add key="Product" value="Sun" />'))`

Comment: that looks like an XML file. have you tried treating it as such?

Comment: @Panomosh: Thanks for the update, this was fairly easy and simple. I feel so stupid now

Comment: Don't be silly - sometimes you just need someone elses eyes. It's very easy to get locked onto looking into something from the wrong angle. We all end up there :)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to expand the text string you're looking for in the replace, verbatim. No reason to digress into regex. Also need something to modify (or make a modified copy of) the config file, Out-File used here for plain text.

```
$test = ((Get-Content -path "C:\Powershell\test.txt" -Raw) -replace '"SourceRepository" value="Sun"','"SourceRepository" value="Mock"')
Out-File -InputObject $test -FilePath "C:\Powershell\output.txt"
```